# Meaning of the phrase "go from" in context

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in Crash Course Astronomy, episod 11[https://youtu.be/w-9gDALvMF4][1] The sentence is at the beginning of the video.

> *The Earth went from being our unique planet in the universe to one of many such well... planets.*

I have checked all the meanings of the word "go", but still have a hard time understanding the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of its meaning, here's what the sentence in question is saying:

It was once thought that the Earth was the center of our entire world (that's why it was considered unique). But as time went by and scientific progress marched on, scientists like Nicolaus Copernicus, Galileo Galilei and many other great people like them proved that not only was the Earth not the the center of our solar system, but it was also not the center of the universe at large. So, as it turned out, Earth was just a regular planet no different from other celestial bodies out there. That's how it went from being a unique thing in the entire universe to something that's very minuscule in its significance and not unique at all.

The expression *to go from something to something else* itself means to go from one state to another or [**to go from one extreme to the other**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+from+one+extreme+to+the+other). Initially, you are one thing, but as time goes on and things change, you become something completely different from or even the opposite of what you originally were. The following example will show you how you can use this phrase in a sentence:

> In one year, she **went from** waitressing **to** earning millions of dollars as YouTube's most popular video blogger. That's quite a transformation!

Comment: No, there is no extremes, sorry. He went from being silly to being funny. It's just one condition or state to another, not necessarily the antithesis of each other. It could be a continuum.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the comment. But being silly and funny are, in a way, the extremes of each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is a metaphorical use of normal "go", which means change places, *go from here to there*. Only in this case, the place that has been changed is in our head—our view of the importance that the Earth occupied. It used to be that we didn't know how many planets existed, so Earth was #1. It now went (in our mind) from the #1 position to the #19484575620457...... position. (Of course, there is no such ranking, but you get the point.)

З унікальної вона **стала** однією з багатьох.

Answer (score 0):

"Go", as you already know, means to change location. "To go from here to there" means that an entity moves from his current position or place of stay("here") to "there".

The speaker of the given sentence says that the Earth has moved from it's position of being a unique planet in the universe to not being unique anymore due to the fact that scientists have discovered many other Earth-like planets. Earth-like in the sense that the other planets may also support life or have oxygen or water and so on.